# What is the minimum amount of memory required for starting a process on a Linux-based system?

Tags: process, memory, concurrency

> [Routines in both languages are inexpensive](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/comparing-elixir-go): goroutines are 2KB each, while Elixir processes are 0.5KB each.

I understand that to start a process in [BEAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BEAM_(Erlang_virtual_machine)) requires 0.5KB of memory. This being so lightweight in the case of [Elixir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elixir_(programming_language)) and Erlang, and to a lesser degree in the case of [Go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_(programming_language)) seems to be the advantage of using these runtimes when compared with other languages that rely on either their own not that inexpensive processes and threads or [on the underlying OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8623573/what-is-a-python-thread)'s processes and threads (that also supposedly require more memory).

I want to know how much memory requires starting a process on a Linux-based system.
I am aware that the memory usage depends on what the process is doing. But I assume that there is a memory cost of just starting a process that does nothing). What is that cost?
Where can I read more about it? Are there any files / commands with which I can inspect this?

Comment: @terdon I'm thinking about a process that does absolutely nothing. I've just modified my question in response to your comment.

Comment: If a process forks and does (almost) nothing, it will probably share all its memory pages with its parent via COW.  But likely it has to have at least its own stack page (so it has somewhere to do that nothing).  And activities in the parent could cause COW pages to be copied, further increasing memory use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Linux, any thread or process incurs at least the cost of a `task_struct` in the kernel; on my system, `pahole task_struct` tells me that that takes 9,344 bytes. In user-space, a thread will also need a stack to be allocated to it, but the actual cost of that will depend on how much stack space it really uses (since only pages which are touched will be allocated).

You can use the example programs in [`man pthread_attr_init`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_attr_init.3.html) and [`pthread_create`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html). The latter in particular allows you to control both the stack size and the number of created threads, which means that the cost of a single thread in user-space can be estimated by running it and measuring the amount of memory it uses. GNU `time`, averaging over a large number of runs, suggests a 48KiB penalty per thread in this particular scenario, with a 64KiB stack.

Forking is somewhat more expensive since that involves creating a new address space for the process, with associated structures in the kernel and page-table entries.

Comment: `pahole task_struct |grep size` outputs, among other lines: `/* size: 9472, cachelines: 148, members: 232 */` Is then the cost of a `task_struct` on my system 9472 bytes?

Comment: That’s right, or perhaps more accurately, three pages (12KiB).